# UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert add button not working

Tags: ios, uitableview

I would like to call a method after pressing the add button of a UITableView cell with style `UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert`. I have been using `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` but I just realized that this method only works when the cell "body" is pressed, not the button.

I have tried using `tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:` but this method seems to work only for UITableViewCell accessories.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, I tested in a Test app and tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: works. Could you post relevant code to see what's happening? See screenshot http://img407.imageshack.us/img407/3668/ukbs.png

Comment: Thank you Teofilo. I was able to solve the problem as I show above.

Comment: If you post the solution as an answer and mark it, others may benefit as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert)
    {
        NSLog(@"UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert");
        //Perform relevant task here
    }
}
```